# I want to know when a file is done downloading

Tags: php, streaming, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to know when download is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584424/how-to-know-when-download-is-finished)

Hi,

I have a file which I want users to download only once.  After it's done downloading, the file is no longer available.

Outside of setting up a streaming system, is there any way I can set some sort of callback up to say the file is done downloading on the client's computer?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584424/how-to-know-when-download-is-finished

Answer (score -1):

You can use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)() to send the file then do what you need to do.

```
header( 'content-type: file/type' );
readfile($filename);
file_is_done_downloading();
```

It's usually best to let people download for an hour or two just to make sure they get everything, since this doesn't support resuming downloads.